# Change Default Web Browser via Access vba

Tags: google-chrome, ms-access, vba

My default web browser is Google Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m. The following web address does not work properly in Chrome but does so in IE: "https://secure.crbonline.gov.uk/enquiry/multipleEnquirySearch.do". I have written the follwing code to try to open the link in IE but what it does is open IE and then open the hyperlink in Chrome. How can I get it to simply open in IE and not run Chrome in this instance?

```
Dim stAppName As String
stAppName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
Call Shell(stAppName, 1)
FollowHyperlink "https://secure.crbonline.gov.uk/enquiry/multipleEnquirySearch.do"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including the URL along with stAppName.

```
Dim strApp  As String
Dim strURL As String

strApp = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
strURL = "https://secure.crbonline.gov.uk/enquiry/multipleEnquirySearch.do"
Call Shell(strApp & " " & strURL, 1)
```